Are Bird Trills Consonants or Vowels?
Not sure if this is the right place for this.
I was wondering what the specifics of a vowel or a consonant are. Are bird trills like This or This considered vowels or consonants? Also, how could they be approximated with the IPA?
Any help appreciated; I do not know much.
Thank You!

Current approximation is /a/ and /æ/ respectively

Birds don’t have vocal folds or use their larynx or tongue in producing sound the way humans do, so I don’t think it makes sense to apply human-based notions like ‘consonant’, ‘vowel’ or IPA transcription to bird vocalisations at all.

birds do not have speech, except parrots sort of.

There are a couple different definitions of "consonant" and "vowel".
One is an articulatory definition: consonants involve more closure of the vocal tract than vowels. But for this definition to work, we need some reference points: some things that we definitely want to consider vowels, and some things that we definitely want to consider consonants. This means we can't really use this definition for birds yet. (We can't use human sounds as reference points because a human vocal tract is so different from a bird one.)
Another is a phonological definition: every syllable contains exactly one vowel, so a sound is a vowel if it acts as a syllable nucleus, and a consonant if it doesn't. But for this definition to work, we'd first need to establish that birdsong has a "syllable structure" to it, because it's not at all obvious that it does.
As a result, we can't really call those sounds either consonants or vowels—our definitions just don't apply to them! We could discuss the sounds humans make to imitate those sounds, potentially, but not the birdsong itself.

What term would you recommend to describe them?

@AnonymousCoder Honestly, I don't think any linguistics terminology will really be useful here. At least not until you've done some analysis of the structure. Maybe musical terminology would be better?

ornithologists / bird ethologists have their own terminology to describe song structure. I'm not one of them, but my recollection from a handful of lectures/talks over the years is that they've never used "consonant" or "vowel", but they do use "syllables" and/or "phrases" as a way to talk about sequences that get repeated. this Scientific American article demonstrates it (cf. the figure about "paired syllables").  Other terms I've heard used include "chirp" (quickly rising pitch), "warble" (oscillating pitch), and "whistle" (near-pure tone / few harmonics).
